# why throw java.awt.FontFormatException, however i can open the tff file in windows

Tags: java, fonts

the code is below:

```
Font getFont(String fontPath) throws IOException, FontFormatException {
        fis = new FileInputStream(fontPath);
        bis = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(fis);
        Font tmp = null;
        try {
            tmp = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, bis);
        } catch (FontFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            bis.close();
            fis = new FileInputStream(fontPath);
            bis = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(fis);
            tmp = Font.createFont(Font.TYPE1_FONT, bis);
        }

        return tmp.deriveFont(96.0f);
    }
```

this code is not always work!!!.
it will throw java.awt.FontFormatException for some font file, however, that font file can be open correctly in windows...why

it will first throw:
java.awt.FontFormatException: Font name not found

and then throw:
java.awt.FontFormatException: bad pfa font

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. I figured out that the TTF file is written to a temp file. This file is then processed, and a FontFormatException(font name not found) exception is thrown because this property is not set in the TrueTypeFont instance. Which is kind of strange, because I have verified the metadata of the tmp font file, and this file does contain the required metadata.

Comment: .. And I have fixed the issue by downloading the TTF files from the web. I guess that foo.TTF for OSX is not the same as foo.TTF for Windows. However, by replacing all my embedded fonts with the downloaded font, I finally fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this on your computer. Replace `rootPath` with the path to your fonts.

```
public class FontLoader {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String rootPath = "/Library/Fonts";

        File root = new File(rootPath);
        if (root.canRead()) {
            String[] fontFiles = root.list();

            Font font = null;
            for (String fontFile : fontFiles) {
                try {
                    System.out.println(fontFile);
                    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(root
                            + "/" + fontFile));
                    System.out.println(font);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to run indefinite number of times without fail, and if so then you might want to restructure your code somewhat - the stacking of close/open on your input streams looks somewhat suspicious. I say this without seeing where you are declaring those instance variables and what other code might be manipulating them.